# Thousand separator in pie chart of charts.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I 'm using Chart.js to draw pie chart.

To draw graph I used

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
          labels: #{raw @labels.to_json},
          datasets: [{
          backgroundColor: #{raw @colors.to_json},
            data: #{@followers}
          }]
        }
      });
```

To clarify this data thing is like this

```
data: {
      labels: ["FAISAL","muhammadfaisali","faisaliqbal3699"],
      datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: ["#00b638","#efaa30","#50c8ea"],
        data: [500000, 75000, 100000]
      }]
    }
```

I need to show these `data: [500000, 75000, 100000]` as thousand separator like `["500,000", "75,000", "100,000"]`

I tried different

things including writing this method

```
function separator(numbers)
      { data = []
        for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i) {
          data.push(numbers[i].toLocaleString())
        }
        data
      }
```

and tried to use it like this

```
data: separator(#{@followers})
```

it format data as I want but gives error like `Cannot read property 'custom' of undefined`

What is the way to show data in thousand separator here

[image: showing it like this now]

Comment: Can you check first [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)? You usually format your data right before rendering. Not sure when/if that happens in charts.js.

The property error can occur when not all your data are integers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to do this in chart.js, you need to use the [`tooltips.callbacks.label`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-tooltip-configuration) callback property.  The value returned from this callback is what is used to generate the tooltip text.

Here is your chart configured with a tooltip callback that uses the local string representation for your data value.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
var myPie = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ["FAISAL","muhammadfaisali","faisaliqbal3699"],
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: ["#00b638","#efaa30","#50c8ea"],
      data: [500000, 75000, 100000]
    }],
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Employee Overview',
      fontStyle: 'bold',
      fontSize: 20
    },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        // this callback is used to create the tooltip label
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          // get the data label and data value to display
          // convert the data value to local string so it uses a comma seperated number
          var dataLabel = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
          var value = ': ' + data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index].toLocaleString();

          // make this isn't a multi-line label (e.g. [["label 1 - line 1, "line 2, ], [etc...]])
          if (Chart.helpers.isArray(dataLabel)) {
            // show value on first line of multiline label
            // need to clone because we are changing the value
            dataLabel = dataLabel.slice();
            dataLabel[0] += value;
          } else {
            dataLabel += value;
          }

          // return the text to display on the tooltip
          return dataLabel;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

You can see it in action at this [codepen](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/yMGKKE).

Comment: Thousand separators should be driven by localisation, this solution, albeit correct for non-localised scenarios, does not take this into consideration. I.e en = 1,000.00, pt = 1.000,00